# How to configure Terminal Emulator on Alpine Linux?

Tags: alpine-linux

I am using XFCE and when I clicked on Terminal Emulator its ask you to put what program to execute. I wrote "terminal" and now it shows this message:

> "Failed to execute child process "terminal" (no such file or directory).

I know that I incorrectly typed "terminal" but I don't know how to fix it.

[image: Alpine Linux running on VirtualBox]

Comment: May you please provide screen shots of the messages you are seeing in your question?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBuE1.png

Comment: What if you type "bash"

Comment: That's the problem. Where would I type "bash" if I cannot open Terminal?

Comment: In the question you mention typing the word "terminal". I meant to type it in that location. Can you use the gui to figure out where the terminal program is installed? Mine is at /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator and another is at/usr/bin/gnome-terminal. You most likely have to specify the full path

Answer (score 1):

You would have to specify what to run when you click on Terminal Emulator. This would be the shell, most likely `/usr/bin/x-session-terminal`. Type that or use `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal` rather than using the actual keyword "Terminal" as there is no program that actually is named terminal to execute; "Terminal" is the icon name. The easiest way to find installed terminals is to look for them in your file viewer (Thunar) or to switch to a tty (Ctrl-Alt-F#) and use the whereis command.

Comment: Maybe you mean `x-terminal-emulator`? That's specific to Debian and its derivatives.

Answer (score 1):

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to get to the second console
2. Login & password
3. `apk add xfce4-terminal`, `reboot`
4. Applications > Settings > Preferred Applications > Utilities

   And set Terminal Emulator to XFCE Terminal.